# Propagating MouseArea events from parent to child

Tags: qml, mousearea

I have a global `MouseArea` *mouseAreaRoot* taking the whole screen to prevents actions on specific buttons when a popup is opened.

Within the `QML` objects below this global `MouseArea`, I have a nested `MouseArea` *nestedMenuMouseArea* handling the clicks on my menu.

The problem is that when I click on the menu, the mouse events are redirected to `mouseAreaRoot` and not `nestedMenuMouseArea`. This is the behaviour one would expect, since the global `MouseArea` covers the entire screen.

I would like to exclude *nestedMenuMouseArea* from the effects of *mouseAreaRoot* which prevents any actions on the other `QML` objects.

I read about the [propagateComposedEvents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) attribute, but it only seems to work from **child to parent**.

I would like the opposite: detect from *mouseAreaRoot* a click onto *nestedMenuMouseArea* and dispatch the event to it in order to trigger its `onClicked` code.

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of explaining your code.

Comment: As for you issue - you should set [MouseEvent.accepted](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mouseevent.html#accepted-prop) to false along with [propagateComposedEvents: true](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop)

Answer (score 2):

As no code is here, we can not find visual stacking order.

The complete mouse area events propagation is based on your visual stacking order.

If A is parent Item, B and C are A's children, D and E are C's children...

Something like:

```
A{
    B{}

    C{
       D{}
       E{}
     }
 }
```

The rough visual stacking order is (if Z value is not exclusively specified),

```
E D C B A.
```

So the mouse area event propagation, starts from E and reaches to A.

Unless some where mouse area's `enabled` property is exclusively set to false.

So first and most important thing you have to look for is.... How your QML parent- children are arranged.

And next is check if `enabled` is false for the mouse area.

and next like "folibs" said in comment,ensure you set `MouseEvent.accepted` to false along with `propagateComposedEvents: true`